# Trying to reload UITableView every time the user goes back to the page, but it isn't working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I tried to use

```
func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.myTableName.reloadData()
}
```

but it didn't work or reload when I went back to the page in the simulator. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you forgot to override the method

Comment: @LeoDabus oh yeah, the override! It didn't give me an error so I didn't notice... thanks

Comment: just to be clear - the problem here is **not** that the you forgot to override the method, it's that without the firs parameter label `_`, insignificant though it is, you were providing something close to the expected method, but not actually the right method at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `_` as first parameter label in Swift 3, so change your method with below one and add `override` prefix before it also call the `super.viewDidAppear(animated)` .

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.myTableName.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Don't forget the call to `super`.

Comment: oh, ok! It didn't give me an error so I didn't realize. This worked beautifully, thank you!